# C# ticket distribution per customer exercise

Tags: c#, console

I need your help on this exercise. I need to distribute the ticket per customer. If ticket is more than the customer the ticket will be added to the first customer and so on.

Example:

```
Enter ticket number: 10

Enter customer number: 5
```

Result:

```
customer#1 ticket#1 ticket#6
customer#2 ticket#2 ticket#7
customer#3 ticket#3 ticket#8
customer#4 ticket#4 ticket#9
customer#5 ticket#5 ticket#10
```

Here is my code so far that can cater only the first loop of the customer but the succeeding ticket is my problem.

```
List<int> customerNumberList = new List<int>();
List<int> ticketNumberList = new List<int>();

Console.Write("Enter Numer of Tickets: ");
int ticketCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter Number of Customer: ");
int customerCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for(int i = 1; i <= ticketCount; i++)
{
    ticketNumberList.Add(i);
}

for(int i = 1; i <= customerCount; i++)
{
    customerNumberList.Add(i);
}

if(customerNumberList.Count == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Customer#1");

    for (int i = 0; i < ticketNumberList.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ticket#" + ticketNumberList[i]);
    }
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < customerNumberList.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Customer#" + customerNumberList[i]);

        for(int j = 0; j <ticketNumberList.Count; j++)
        {
            if(customerNumberList[i] == ticketNumberList[j])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ticket#" + ticketNumberList[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks, everyone

Comment: It's difficult to discern what you're asking beyond "Please solve my homework".  How is your current code not working as expected?  When you *debug* your code (actually stepping through it in a debugger and observing the runtime values and behavior), where specifically does it first differ from what you expect?  What operation or line of code first produces an unexpected result?  What were the inputs?  What result was observed?  What result was expected?  Why?  If you just need tips on how to debug, this is quite helpful: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Question is not clear to me.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Try using a `List<List<int>> customersWithTheirTickets`, with a `int remainingTickets = ticketCount;`. Then cycle the `customersWithTheirTickets`, subtracting 1 from `remainingTickets` and adding a new ticket to the "current" `customersWithTheirTickets` until there are no remaining `remainingTickets`

Comment: Please review this code. Debug it, try to refactor it. Most important try to understand it. https://github.com/asc89cr/Tickets/blob/master/Program.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
Ask for `int ticketCount`
Ask for `int customerCount`

customersWithTickets = List<int>[customerCount] (so an array of customers, each element is the list of the tickets of the customer)

set each element of customersWithTickets to a `new List<int>()`

int remainingTickets = ticketCount
int currentTicketNumber = 1

while remainingTickets != 0
    for each customersWithTickets
        add to current customersWithTickets the value of currentTicketNumber
        increment currentTicketNumber
        decrement remainingTickets

        if remainingTickets == 0 then break the for cycle
    end for
end while

for each customersWithTickets i = [0..customersWithTickets.Length[
    print customer#, without going to new line

    for each ticket of the current customersWithTickets j = [0..customersWithTickets[i].Count[
        print ticket# (`customersWithTickets[i][j]`), without going to new line
    end for

    print new line
end for

print the customers, each one with its ticket.
```

You can clearly go another way (we will call this way the "cheating" way): you don't really need to store the single tickets of the customers to print them. You can simply notice that if there are 13 tickets and there are 5 customers, each customer has 13 /  5 = 2 tickets (where / is the integer division), plus 13 mod 5 = 3 (mod is the remainder of the division, % in C#) the first 3 customers have an additional ticket. For the exact numbers of the tickets it is even easier:

```
the customer 1 will have 3 tickets: 1, 6, 11 
the customer 2 will have 3 tickets: 2, 7, 12
the customer 3 will have 3 tickets: 3, 8, 13
the customer 4 will have 2 tickets: 4, 9
the customer 5 will have 2 tickets: 5, 10
```

I hope that it is clear that each custome will have tickets in the form:

```
the customer x will have n tickets (calculated as above): 
    (x + 0 * num of customers), 
    (x + 1 * num of customers), 
    (x + 2 * num of customers), 
    ...
```